# Value accessibility across files in Python

Tags: python

I have a file structure as follows

```
Folder1:
Folder2
Class-with-global-variables-and-static-methods-to-modify-them.py

Folder2:
Myfile-1.py
Myfile-2.py
Master.py
```

Master.py imports the other 2 files in its folder. The " Class-with-global-variables-and-static-methods-to-modify-them.py" is never instantiated and the global values in it are modified via static methods. But I want these modifications to persist globally.

ex:

```
 class Class-with-global-variables-and-static-methods-to-modify-them:

 ...
 ...
 importance = 0
 ...
 ...
 @staticmethod
 def modifyImportance(value):
      Class-with-global-variables-and-static-methods-to-modify-them.imortance = 1
```

If Myfile-1.py modified the value of importance I want the new value of importance to be available to Myfile-2.py if It tried to access it.

Comment: Are the `Myfile-1` and `Myfile-2` modules being executed/called during the same execution context, or are you trying to preserve state between different executions?

Comment: The same execution context. Ideadlly Master.py may invoke Myfile-1 and Myfile-2 but not neccesarily in a pre-defined order

Answer (score 0):

What you have already would work, but you're doing it wrong.

There is no point in Python in having a class that is never instantiated and which only contains static variables. Python is not Java, and doesn't require classes. Instead, just define the variables at module level and modify them directly.

Comment: How would I define them at a module level? And how would 2 modules share the values?

Answer (score -2):

I think you just need to append global before your var and things should work

```
class Class-with-global-variables-and-static-methods-to-modify-them:
...
 global importance
 importance = 0
 ...
 ...
 @staticmethod
 def modifyImportance(value):
      Class-with-global-variables-and-static-methods-to-modify-them.imortance = 1
```

Comment: This will make it accessible across files?

Comment: No. I think I misunderstood the question. :(